# How to use "eh" as "anyway"?

Tags: german-to-english, particle, spoken-language

Examples:

- Ich habe eh keinen Bock, ins Kino zu gehen  -- I don't wanna go to
  the cinema anyway.
- Of course I don't mind taking you home - I'm going that way anyway.
- Die kaputte Vase hat mir eh nie gefallen. -- I never liked the broken vase anyway.

How to use the particle "eh" in general with the meaning of "anyway" ?

In those cases, can "doch", "sowieso", "halt" or any other particle be used instead ?

Comment: You should give a number of concrete examples (sentences with "anyway" where you believe you can use "eh"). You can hardly expect that people who know the intricacies of using "eh" are also pros in the use of "anyway" in English.

Comment: After you addeded examples: your examples are correct and good. It seems you have a good understanding of the correct use of "eh". Regarding synonyms and other substitutes for "eh": "Sowieso" is a synonym of "eh". "Doch" has a different function and meaning, usually some form of intensifier (but see the entries about "doch" here in the forum). "Halt" again is different; usually it is used too express something like "I ask for your understanding".

Comment: Note this answer is slightly different when you ask an Austrian and a German native speaker. (Where's @HubertSchönlast when you need him?)

Comment: Austrians use "eh" a lot; "du kennst ihn eh?" (meaning "Du kennst ihn doch, oder?"), and also in expressions: "Hab ich dir eh gesagt" ("Ich hab's Dir gesagt, wirklich!") - something added to a sentence to express the assumption of a positive reply. Also worth a notice: "eh schon wissen!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The particles **eh** and **sowieso** means you have given up (something), it doesn't matter to you anymore.

> Dir ist dein Fahrrad geklaut worden? – Es war kaputt.

*Your bike has been stolen? – It's broken.*

> Dir ist dein Fahrrad geklaut worden? – Es war **eh/sowieso** kaputt.

*Your bike has been stolen? – It's broken **anyway, I don't care.***

The particle **doch** mean the exact opposite here, you care very much:

> Dir ist dein Fahrrad geklaut worden? – Es war **doch** noch wie neu.

*Your bike has been stolen? – It was like new, **why me**.*

The particle **halt** gives a reason:

> Dir ist dein Fahrrad geklaut worden? – Es war **halt** wie neu.

*Your bike has been stolen? – It was like new, **that's why**.*

Comment: Can "sowieso" be used to change a topic? Like: Anyway, as I said, I'll be away next week.

Comment: *Anyway* neither translates into *eh* nor *sowieso* in that context. That *anyway* translates to German *Wie auch immer, …* or *So oder so, …*

Comment: Giving translations for these modal particles is a bit problematic because in English there are not used as often as in German. But I think if you want a translation for *eh/sowieso* *anyway* is the closest possible translation.

Comment: **eh** and **sowieso** are by no means meaning that you have given up something. It is closer to meaning that one fact fits good to another fact. Example: "Willst du mit in den Zoo kommen? Prima Idee! Das wollte ich **eh** schon lange mal wieder machen."

Comment: @Janka "sowieso" = "so wie so" = "so oder so" (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sowieso)

Comment: Ich kenne ehrlich gesagt niemanden, der *so wie so* an Stelle von *so oder so* verwendet.

Comment: @Gerhardh: eh/sowieso/ohnehin wollen == Ich gebe meinen Widerstand auf/Ich habe nichts dagegen.

Comment: Um den Widerstand aufgeben zu können, müsste man vorher doch ersteinmal Widerstand leisten. Ist man hingegen sofort begeistert von dem Vorschlag, kann kaum von Widerstand geredet werden.

Comment: Nimm den Satz mal ohne die anderen Partikel: *Das wollte ich machen.* *Das wollte ich **eh** machen.* Das *eh* entwertet den Vorschlag/Befehl als "halb so wild".

Comment: In diesem Satz wird "eh" nicht im Sinne von "sowieso" verwendet: "Kommst du heute **eh**?" - Kommst du heute **sicher/wirklich**?

Comment: Das muss dann aber eine spezifisch süddeutsche Unterscheidung sein. Hier im Norden gibt es keinen Unterschied zu *Kommst du heute sowieso?*

Comment: So in the two examples, **eh** and **sowieso** are interchangeable? Das versteht er **sowieso** nicht. --- Das versteht er **eh** nicht.

Comment: It seems Southern speakers make a difference. In the North, *sowieso* is more prevalent and *eh* is seen as a drop-in for *sowieso*.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a number of sentences where "eh" is used in a typical way (in well-formed oral German):

> A: "Hör auf mit Arbeiten, es gibt Essen!" - B: "Na gut, ich hab eh keine Kraft mehr."
>
> A: "Du, ich habe heute glaub ich doch keine Zeit für einen Spaziergang." - B: "Schon gut, heute ist eh Sauwetter."
>
> "Ich gehe diesmal nicht zum Wählen. Die Wahl ist eh gelaufen."
>
> "Du brauchst dich nicht zu beeilen. Der Zoo hat eh schon zu."
>
> "Lass ihn doch in Ruh. Er hört eh nichts."

It seems "eh" is quite synonym to "sowieso" or "ohnehin" and "ohnedies" in more formal registers of language.

Comment: "Hör auf mit Arbeiten, es gibt Essen!" klingt eher wie aus nem schlechten RTL-Nachmittagsprogramm... "Hör auf zu arbeiten, (...)" (bzw. als für mich gefühlt schlechte alternative "Hör auf mit dem arbeiten, (...)") wäre eine bessere alternative...

Comment: @TopQuestions. - Vielleicht sprechen wir zuhause ja wie bei RTL im Nachmittagsprogramm. (Komisch jedoch, wir haben gar keinen Fernseher, und von RTL kennen ich gerade mal den Namen.) - Vermutlich sind einfach in verschiedenen Gegenden, Kreisen, Familien etc. verschiedene Formulierungen üblich.

Comment: Sorry, klang vielleicht ein bisschen "abwertend" und negativ, sollte nicht so rüberkommen, bin selbst oftmals nicht besser. Diese "Verstümmelung" der Sprache sticht mir nur manchmal recht stark in den Magen, bitte entschuldige, war da eher von akuten Gefühlen geleitet worden.

Comment: Die Fragestellung verleitete aber auch mit dazu denke ich mal. Im sprachlichen sieht es natürlich auch immer noch ein wenig anders aus...hier ging es ja auch eher um das Sprachliche und "zwischen Tür und Angel". "Toxic" triffts wohl für das eher, was ich dir als Kommentar hinterlassen habe, tut mir Leid.

Answer (score 0):

"Eh" is "dismissive," and translates well into "anyway" You can use "sowieso," (roughly, "so what?") synonymously.

"Doch" is used in the opposite manner, for emphasis. "Der Film war doch interressant." The film was really interesting.

"Halt" is a "hook," or connecting expression. "Sie ist beliebt, sie ist halt schön." She is popular "because" she is pretty.